# Rupee symbol not showing in JMeter

Tags: fonts, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to test some of my REST web services using JMeter. The response contains the rupee symbol (₹). The symbol is not showing up in JMETER which I believe is due to absence of a supported font.

Can I add the font/s to JMETER. Is there a way to assert the symbol without adding any font. I may have to do it for some other currency symbols.

Currently the symbol (showing up correctly in 'Postman' and other browser extension tools) is showing up as  -

```
"availablecurrency":{"INR":"."},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Being properly configured JMeter can deal with any symbol.

I suggest the following:

1. Use UTF-8 encoding for JMeter in generat
2. Use UTF-8 for HTTP Request Sampler

See picture below for proof of concept:

[image: Rupee sign]

To set HTTP Request encoding just type it into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Content Encoding input. For this demo I used `UTF-8`

To tell JMeter to use UTF-8 put the following line into *system.properties* file

```
file.encoding=UTF-8
```

and restart JMeter.

Alternatively you can provide this property as a command-line argument as

```
jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them.

Comment: No luck yet. Still getting the currency as earlier.